# Extension Degree of Fields Composite

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $K/F$ be a field extension, $L/F$ and $M/F$ finite subextensions of $K/F$ and $LM$ the composite of $L$ and $M$. I'm trying to prove that $[LM:F] = [L:F][M:F]$ implies the trivial intersection $L\cap M=F$, and that the converse holds when $[L:F]=2$ or $[M:F]=2$.

In order to prove the trivial intersection of the fields, I want to show that $[L\cap M:F]=1$. From the hypothesis, we can obtain
$$[LM:L] = [M:F] = [M:L\cap M][L\cap M:F],$$
and
$$[LM:M] = [L:F] = [L:L\cap M][L\cap M:F],$$
but I don't if that is usefull for what I'm trying to prove. And I don't know how to prove the converse part. I would appreciate any help you can give me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll draw this diagram of fields in a slightly odd manner, since I'm limited by the MathJax.

$$\require{AMScd}\begin{CD}LM @<<< L \\ @AAA @AAA\\M @<<<L\cap M @<<< F\end{CD}$$

Now we have
$$[LM:L]=[M:F]=[M:L\cap M][L\cap M:F],$$
as you've already noted.
Note now that $[LM:L]\le [M:L\cap M]$, so that
$$[M:L\cap M][L\cap M:F]\le [M:L\cap M],$$
or
$$[L\cap M:F]\le 1,$$
which of course implies that $L\cap M=F$.

Comment: Thank you very much! That was very helpful.