# A doubt on generalizing a result on Extension fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I had a doubt in generalizing a result on extension of fields involving composites. Upon searching, I came across this [Extension Degree of Fields Composite](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3055356/extension-degree-of-fields-composite).
We have a result that, if $L$ and $M$ are two finite extensions of a field $F,$ then
$$[LM:F] \leq [L:F][M:F]$$ with the equality if and only if an $F$-basis for one of the fields remains linearly independent over the other.

Then I thought of writing that result as follows without the use of inequality.   $$[LM:F]=\frac{[L:F][M:F]}{[L \cap M:F]}$$
I am not sure whether this is true or not.

The doubt is about the equality in the above result.

**My attempt:** $F$-basis for $L/F$ will have $1$ in it. Similarly, $F$-basis for $M/F$ will have $1$ in it. In their intersection, we will have $1.$ I am not able to go ahead.

In the case of the linked question, it is stated that the converse given there holds good when $[L:F]=2$ or $[M:F]=2.$ I could not get why this is true.

Any ideas on how to progress will be of great help.

Answer (score 1):

We may as well assume that $L\cap M=F$, so the question is whether if $L\cap M=F$ then $[LM:F]=[L:F][M:F]$.  Translating this into group theory via the Galois correspondence, this is asking whether if $H$ and $K$ are subgroups of a finite group $G$ which together generate $G$, then $[G:H\cap K]=[G:H][G:K]$.  This is not true: for instance, if $G=S_3$ then you could take $H$ and $K$ to be the subgroups generated by two different $2$-cycles, and then $[G:H\cap K]=6\neq 9=[G:H][G:K]$.

In terms of fields, if you take a Galois extension $E/F$ with Galois group $S_3$, it will have three different subfields of degree $3$ over $F$ (corresponding to the three subgroups of $S_3$ of order $2$).  If you take $L$ and $M$ to be two of these subfields, then $LM=E$ and $L\cap M=F$, but $[E:F]=6\neq 9=[L:F][M:F]$.

Very explicitly, for instance, you could take $F=\mathbb{Q}$, $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt[3]{2})$, and $M=\mathbb{Q}(e^{2\pi i/3}\sqrt[3]{2})$.  Then $[L:F]=[M:F]=3$ but $[LM:F]=6$.  ($L$ and $M$ are formed by adjoining two different roots of $x^3-2$ and $LM$ is the splitting field of $x^3-2$.)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Eric_Wofsey. Actually, I have not yet started studying the Galois theory. So, it is becoming difficult for me to understand this answer. If possible, please provide an explanation purely in Extension field terms. Thank you once again.

Comment: I understood the counterexample. Thanks for helping @Eric_Wofsey.